# Turn absolute file paths and line numbers in the tool output into hyperlinks

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, elm, jetbrains-ide

This is an example output:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/elm-make src/elm/Main.elm --output=builds/main.js
-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------- src/elm/Main.elm

The type annotation for `init` does not match its definition.

35| init : Maybe Route.Location -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The type annotation is saying:

    Maybe Route.Location -> ( { route : Maybe Route.Location }, Cmd Msg )

But I am inferring that the definition has this type:

    Maybe Route.Location
    -> ( { route : Maybe Route.Location -> Route.Model }, Cmd a )

Detected errors in 1 module.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the regex that i came up with:

http://regexr.com/3egqu

However, creating output filter out of it like this:

[image]

doesn't work.

Thus far, I only know that the following works: `------ ($FILE_PATH$)`

And it turns the file path into a link:

[image]

Help me find a way to include the line numbers into the links.

Comment: bug reported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163116#u=1477401090606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with;

First,

```
elm-make --report json
```

outputs the build errors in structured JSON;

```
$ elm-make --report json src/main.elm
[{"tag":"unused import","overview":"Module `Bootstrap.CDN` is unused.","details":"Best to remove it. Don't save code quality for later!","region":{"start":{"line":3,"column":1},"end":{"line":3,"column":28}},"type":"warning","file":"src/main.elm"}]
```

Now you can pipe that output through `jq` [(see here).](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to reformat it into

```
elm make src/main.elm --report json --output ./public/app.js | \
jq '.[] | { type: .type, file: .file, line: .region.start.line|tostring, tag: .tag, column: .region.start.column|tostring, tag: .tag, details: .details }' | \
jq --raw-output '. | "[" + (.type|ascii_upcase) + "] " + .file + ":" + .line + ":" + .column + " " + .tag + " -- " + .details + "\n"'
```

that gives you a reformatted output;

```
[WARNING] src/main.elm:9:1 unused import -- Best to remove it. Don't save code quality for later!

[WARNING] src/main.elm:17:1 missing type annotation -- I inferred the type annotation so you can copy it into your code:

main : Program Never Model Main.Msg
```

Which you pick up in intellij using the format

```
$FILE_PATH$:$LINE$:$COLUMN$ $MESSAGE$
```

You then get to click on an error message to jump to the file, and the error text in a tooltip.